# How to ignore left side space while printing in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying a problem in python. I have some values like 1, 10, 11, 100,... in a queue. When I try to print it in a same line, it has a *leading space*. How to ignore the space? Please help me.

This is my code:

```
import Queue
num = input()
q = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(0,num+1):
  number = i
  temp = []
  while number > 0:
    temp.append(number%2)
    number = number / 2
  temp = temp[::-1]
  number = ''.join(map(str,temp))
  number = number.lstrip()
  q.put(number)
while not q.empty():
  print q.get(),
```

What output I get:

```
 1 10 11 100 101
```

What I need to get:

```
1 10 11 100 101
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `lstrip()` again on the output string:

```
print q.get().lstrip()
```

So all whitespaces from the beginning of the string is removed.

Alternatively, as mentioned in comments by Martijn Pieters, you can avoid pushing empty strings into `q`:

```
  number = number.lstrip()
  if len(number):
    q.put(number)
while not q.empty():
```

Comment: And / or filter out empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

As @iBug mentioned, you could use [`lstrip()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lstrip.htm) to remove all leading white space.

```
print q.get().lstrip()
```

Alternatively, you could slice the string to capture everything after the first character.

```
print q.get()[1:]
```